# how to make svg height match the screen height no matter what device or screen size you are using

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, responsive-design

I need an svg to always match the height of a screen regardless of the platform.
I select the svg in css and set height to 100% or height: 100vh  or min-height:100vh and about 10 other combinations. but when I fiddle with it in the device toolbar I can always find a device it won't work for.

Especially the Ipad.

So I got desperate and used a "onResize" event, and set the height of the svg to the height of the screen with window.innerHeight using javascript.

But apparently onResize is buggy and when it resizes the initial size of the screen is wrong for up to a second or two. 
So I got desprate-ier and wrote this monstrosity. (it works though)

```js
let oldSize = 0; //keeps track of what the size was
function size() {

  if (window.innerHeight != oldSize) { //if the height does not match the old height do something
    oldSize = window.innerHeight; //set the old height to the new height
    $('svg').attr('height', window.innerHeight); //set the height of the svg to the new height
  }
  setTimeout(size, 100); //wait a 10th of a second and try again.
}
size(); //start the recursive loop of desparation.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

so this will check every 10th of a second for a change in window size and then make the svg match the size.

please tell me there is a better way.

Comment: I hope I understand you correctly. In this case you don't need javascript. Add `svg{width:100vw; height:100vh;}`. By default svg is forcing uniform scaling and the circle will stay always in the middle of the svg canvas. Alternatively you may try to add `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"` to the svg element. This will force uniform scaling but will slice those parts of the image that are falling outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener on the window resize event, instead of calling your function every 100 ms:

```js
let oldSize = 0; //keeps track of what the size was

function size() {
  console.log('Resized!');
  if (window.innerHeight != oldSize) { //if the height does not match the old height do something
    oldSize = window.innerHeight; //set the old height to the new height
    $('svg').attr('height', window.innerHeight); //set the height of the svg to the new height
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', size);

size();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```